# how to delete content of input field?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
 <div className="pt-4">
              <label
                htmlFor="location"
                className="block text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700"
              >
                Refferal *
              </label>
              <div className="relative text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-600">
                <div className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center">
                  <SearchIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                </div>
                <input
                  id="search"
                  className="pl-10 p-2 border shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                  placeholder="Search"
                  type="search"
                  name="refferal"
                  value={values.refferal || profile.refferal}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
```

I am prefilling this input field in my react component. Although, I want to change the data inside the field when user type in the field but as user tries to empty the content inside the field. The prefilled data pops up. How to empty the field so that use can update the data accordingly. ?

Comment: share code at codesandbox

Comment: try to use `defaultValue={values.refferal || profile.refferal}` it fills input on mounting (at first time), but after you can change value (https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values)